# Why is the Community user listed on two brand-new sites as having been a member for 3 years and 11 months?

Tags: support, profile-page, community-user

Two new sites ([Proof Assistants](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/) and [Substrate](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/)) came out today, and as of now they're 0 days into their private beta.

Checking on our good robot friend [Community](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) on the Proof Assistants site, I noticed that its profile page says "Member for 3 years, 11 months".  I checked on multiple sites and got the same thing.

[image]

User #1 on the Proof Assistants site, [Adam Lear](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/1/adam-lear), only registered an account today/yesterday. How did the robot get to the sites before they even existed?

Comment: Proof assistants was only proposed 2 months ago: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants

Comment: Given that, I do hope Community has the [precognitive badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/131/precognitive) It certainly deserves it in this case.

Comment: Wrong copy&paste in the database...

Comment: Still happening. 4 years and 4 months on [Bioacoustics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0ugm.png)